# R Plot title includes a url but hyperlink in pdf export does not work ("404" page)

Tags: r, pdf, url, plot

To make it simple here is a very simple plot where I added a url in the subtitle. That url works when I copy/paste it in my browser.
Then I export this plot as pdf. The hyperlink is recognized as a hyperlink, does open a brwoser window with the correct url but I get an "404" page from github.
Any idea why this is that way?

This one works (see pdf here [pdf with hyperlink that works](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j_d8B71-ZmntBczpl7waBNhhj9F6v5JF))

```
plot(x= 1:2, y = 2:3, type = "lines",
     sub = paste0("Source: ", "https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/")) # pdf export hyperlink works
```

but this one below does not work (see pdf here [pdf with hyperlink that does not work](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l0qK44DEgqipd1E0XovE-UjekBOA36AY))

```
plot(x= 1:2, y = 2:3, type = "lines",
         sub = paste0("Source: ","https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19")) # pdf export hyperlink does not work, even though that repo exists
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in a hyphen sign, which you can replace with encoded value `%2D`:

```
https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID%2D19
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks. Indeed that works. It is a pity that my subtitle shows a "weird" link with the %2D  https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID%2D19 . Or maybe I should really ask the owner of that repo to rename it with "_" !